# float vs int when using power function

Tags: c, floating-point

I am trying to run this and cant seem to find out why it wont run. Thank you in advance. Please know I am new.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
float IR;
float invested;
float time;

printf("Please enter the following to be calculated:");
scanf("Interest rate: %f\n", &IR);
scanf("Amount invested: %f\n", &invested);
scanf("Time: %f\n", &time);

float ans;
ans = (invested(((float)1+((IR)^(time)))));

printf("%f", ans);
}
```

Comment: `invested` is what variable or function?

Comment: invested if a float variable.

Comment: To hardcode a float value, just suffix the literal with a `.`, there is no need to cast then. `1` is an integer literal, `1.` is a float literal.

Comment: Also look at http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is not the power function.  you need to use `ans = invested * (1 + pow(IR, time));`

`^` is a Bitwise exclusive OR `XOR`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("Interest rate: %f\n", &IR);
```

You are probably expecting the program to prompt you with the string "Interest rate: " and then process your input. This is not what this statement does. It actually expects *the user* to type "Interest rate: " and then a number.

To prompt the user, use `printf` followed by `scanf`.

```
printf("Interest rate:");
scanf("%f", &IR);
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf` to make sure the input was successfully converted.